# Checkout fails using git-php in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, git, git-checkout

I'm use this lib for php czproject/git-php and when I try do checkout to another branch a I get this error:

```
Command 'git checkout 'qa'' failed (exit-code 1)
```

I try to clone from some repository and then I create a branch and in the same function call I tried to checkout to the new branch

```
use Cz\Git\GitRepository;

//Some code

$this->repo = GitRepository::cloneRepository('/path/to/repository');

//Some code

$this->repo->createBranch('my_branch', TRUE);

local.ERROR: Command 'git checkout 'my_branch'' failed (exit-code 1).
```

Comment: Is this a cli request or a web request? If the latter, does the web user (eg `www-data`) have permissions to change the `.git` directory in the path/to/repository?

Answer (score 0):

The [`czproject/git-php/GitRepository.php#createBranch()`](https://github.com/czproject/git-php/blob/eed45e3201d532c109c6573dff752a9c918dc5b1/src/GitRepository.php#L130-L152) function does call [`checkout()`](http://checkout) (which [calls `run()`](https://github.com/czproject/git-php/blob/eed45e3201d532c109c6573dff752a9c918dc5b1/src/GitRepository.php#L650-L668))

If said checkout fails, it could be because of local changes still in the working tree which would be overridden (unlikey since you just cloned the repo), or because of a file with an invalid name ([as in here](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/208))